# Applet Permanently Loses Focus When Leaving Browser and Coming Back

Tags: java, javascript, swing, browser, applet

I have a web page with an applet as the only element that looks something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>...</title>
</head>
<body>
<applet style="padding:1px; border:1px solid gray" mayscript="mayscript" codebase="..." name="AppletName" code="..." archive="..." width="600" height="500" alt="Alt Text">
  <param name="initial_focus" value="true"/> 
   Alt Text
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page initially loads, focus is set in the applet and I can tab through and interact with the applet just fine.  However, if I leave the browser window and then come back to it, I can no longer regain focus on the applet just using the tab key.

Pressing F5 to reload the page fixes the page so that the Applet regains focus, but this solution is unacceptable.

How do I solve this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: I expect the 'initial_focus' param is only intended to work for when the applet is initially loaded.  Presumably when you navigate to another tab/page and back the focus is lost to the applet so it does not automatically regain it.  OTOH noting that the mayscript flag is added, you might look to a JavaScript based solution to return focus to the applet whenever the page becomes active again.

Comment: @Andrew, indeed, initial_focus parameter isn't really giving me anything because the applet seems to gain focus by default on load anyways. And yes, I've had moderate success using document.AppletName.requestFocus() but I'm struggling to find the ideal event / strategy for detecting when the applet does not have focus and then calling requestFocus.

Comment: I don't delve much into JavaScript, so I don't have any brilliant ideas (Java programmers are almost the worst people on the planet to ask about JS, anyway).  I am guessing there is a javascript tag that you can add to your post?  If so, you might do that & snag the attention of some JS gurus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentative solution:

```
//Dean Edwards/Matthias Miller/John Resig
function init() {
  // quit if this function has already been called
  if (arguments.callee.done) return;

  // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
  arguments.callee.done = true;

  // kill the timer
  if (_timer) clearInterval(_timer);

  window.onfocus = function() {
    if(!document.AppletName.isActive())
      document.AppletName.requestFocus();
  };
}

/* for Mozilla/Opera9 */
if (document.addEventListener) {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
}

/* for Internet Explorer */
/*@cc_on @*/
/*@if (@_win32)
  document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
  var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
  script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
      init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  };
/*@end @*/

/* for Safari */
if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) { // sniff
  var _timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
      init(); // call the onload handler
    }
  }, 10);
}

/* for other browsers */
window.onload = init;
```

Note that the key part for detecting whether the applet needs focus and requesting it if so is (this only works if mayscript is enabled):

```
if(!document.AppletName.isActive())
  document.AppletName.requestFocus();
```

The rest of the code is just attaching the window on focus handling after the page is loaded (using the script JQuery.ready is based off of).

Better solutions welcome.